# Locked from viewing files not listed in VBE Project Explorer as before

Tags: vba, powerpoint, vbe

After a fresh installation of Windows 11 I am unable to see some of my VB projects in the projects window. These projects were locked for viewing and had passwords set.  I know the passwords.

Before the refresh, I could see them listed and was able to operate normally with them. Now, they just don't appear in the VBE Project Explorer.  However, they do appear in the PowerPoint Add-in in the Developer tab.

Comment: The question seems perfectly clear to me and probably to anyone who routinely works with the VBA within PowerPoint add-ins. These are the same people who'd be able to provide the answer Miguel is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean you can see your add-ins listed in the VBA IDE:

Quit PPT if it's running.
Start REGEDIT
Locate:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\Options
```

Under Options, add a new DWORD value named DebugAddins

Set its value to 1

Close REGEDIT, start PPT.